# Converting mp3 to ogg with ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

My goal is to convert `.mp3` to `.ogg`, i googled it and i realized that **ffmpeg** is suitable for this kind of process in php. Well the question is how to run ffmpeg :

I've downloaded the file [from here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg-php/files/latest/download?source=files). The problem is how to use this.

Answer (score 0):

This library is really old (10 years!), I would not recommend it.

You can call process via `exec()` to convert given file - for example:

```
exec("ffmpeg -i $inputPath $outputPath")
```

Of course, you need to have `ffmpeg` package installed on your server.
This is not safe solution and you shouldn't publish this for everyone.